# Demos with persistence fail running locally

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I run the Amazon Alexa video tutorial ["Setup Local Debugging for an Alexa Skill"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLQ8Oaj6Ccw), and debugging is successful on VSCode against "hello World" app, as in the video. However, running against any demo with persistence eg [Cake Walk](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-first-skill) or [High Low](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-highlowgame), the app fails as shown below:

User > start high low game

Alexa > There was a problem with the requested skill's response

Is there some sort of permissions I need to set up to allow access to persistence locally? It's not specified in the tutorials documentation anywhere I can see.

[Note, running from the developer console with the endpoint (re)set to AWS Lambda works.]

debug window gives:

```
~~~~ Error handled: Could not read item
(amzn1.ask.account.AFV5QAE7QCLJQGHTK5EYAWRYARFW3HCGSAGBWXVBSSIGDUT4OR
7YJ23CIPY7PD6LTEREB5URCGCSOPK6J4UDBSQUE6QMYFUQQ44T5KJ62BI3UZYNE4T6CZE
SOP4GYHOJ3JENFM44HKSZY4MC6T564AACOLP7HEIKGXDMN5WJQ7ZIK5GSC66LVRSFOH5H
Q2JXHMG3D3HHMKK42SQ)
from bucket (undefined): Missing required key 'Bucket' in params"
```

Comment: This [developer forum comment](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/224564/ask-s3peristenceadapter-throwing-an-error.html) suggests it might be an issue with `process.env.S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET`. Could explain why it works using a Lambda.

Comment: Thanks, looked at it, but no luck so far....

Comment: go it working. Ran with user version of bucket and  "env": {
                "S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET": "mytbucket", ...to specify it